# Book.all action displaying empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, controller

I'm new to Ruby On Rails development, I'm building an API containing the class user, book, author, and shelf. When I call `Book.all` to retrieve all the books in the Database, I get `[]` in return and don't know what could be the problem. Here are the book migration, book model, and book controller files:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :shelf
end
```

```
class Api::BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    books = Book.all
    render json: book
  end
  
  def show
    book = Book.find(params[:id])
    render json: book
  end
  
  def create
    book = Book.new(book_params)
  
    if book.save
      render json: book, status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: book.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if book.destroy
      render json: { message: 'Book was deleted successfully' }
    else
      render json: { error: 'Failed to delete the Book' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  
  private
  
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

I was expecting to see the names of the books I've created in the database. Here is how I've done it in Rails console:

```
book = Book.new(title: "Pearl of Great Price")
```

Comment: It is a typo. You assign the records from the database to a variable called books (plural), but render book (singular) in the next line in your index method.

Comment: And you get no errors with the above code?

Comment: Hi spickermann, I fixed the typo, but it still returns an empty array. No Stefan, I don't get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors you should address:

1. Here, in the controller action, you should use the `books` local variable, which seems to be a typo (`books` vs `book`):

```
def index
  books = Book.all
  render json: books
end
```

2. In the Rails console, you should "save" the record to the database (the `new` method only initializes the record in memory, see the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create)):

```
Book.create(title: "Pearl of Great Price")  

# You can also do: new + save
book = Book.new(...)
book.save
```

You'll probably need to pass a `user` too, since you have a `belongs_to :user` and a DB constraint, so it needs to be something like:

```
Book.create(title: "...", user: User.last)
```

And finally, as you defined more relations in your model, you'll need to send them in order to create "valid" books:

```
Book.create(title: "...", user: User.last, author: Author.last, shelf: Shelf.last)
```

Of course, you'll need to create those records first. If you don't want all those relations to be mandatory, you can also add the `optional: true` setting in your `belongs_to` associations. More info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Comment: Hi markets, I fixed the typo and saved the record to the database using   Book.create(title: "Pearl of Great Price", user: User.last) but still returns an empty array.

Comment: And if I use puts Book.inspect in the rails c it returns this  Book(id: integer, title: string, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
=> nil

Comment: @Patrick use create! and check which error is coming in console and share it here, Book.create!(title: "Pearl of Great Price", user: User.last)

Comment: Hi hardik,  here is the error coming in console:   User Load (7.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error': Validation failed: User must exist, Author must exist, Shelf must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Comment: @Patrick As you defined more relations in your model, you'll need to send them in order to create "valid" books: `Book.create(title: "...", user: User.last, author: Author.last, shelf: Shelf.last)`. Of course, you'll need to create those records first. If you don't want all those relations to be mandatory, you can also add the `optional: true` setting in your `belongs_to` associations. More info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Hi market, I was able to create books  after  I used  Book.create(title: "Pearl of Great Price", user: User.last, author: Author.last, shelf: Shelf.last) thanks a lot for the help.